# How do you find the ParseRoles currently associated with the current ParseUser?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, parse-platform, querying

I want to populate a `ListView` with an `Array` or an `ArrayList` of the different `ParseRole`s that the current `ParseUser` has associated with them. I presume this requires some kind of query on the current User, however I'm just not really sure how you return the Roles as well as return them into an `Array` or an `ArrayList` with which I could populate a `ListView`. I know you can get the current user using this:

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
```

However I can't from there seem to find how you establish the Roles that the User has been allocated.

EDIT:

I've now also tried experimenting with this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseRole> query = ParseRole.getQuery();
query.whereEqualTo("users", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseRole>() {
   @Override
   public void done(List<ParseRole> objects, ParseException e) {
      if(e == null) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), objects.size() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } else {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
   }                      
});
```

But I still can't seem to get anything to work related to that either. I've currently tried everything I can think of and aren't really getting anywhere as the size of 'objects' is still always 0.

Thanks in advance!

ANSWER:

After implementing the logic behind Marius Falkenberg Waldal's answer and porting it to Android, I managed to finally get a solution that worked for my situation. I've decided to post it in case it helps anyone in the future:

```
    ParseQuery<ParseRole> roleQuery = ParseRole.getQuery();
    List<ParseRole> allRoles = null;
    try {
        allRoles = roleQuery.find();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    userRoles = new ArrayList<ParseRole>();
    userRolesNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(ParseRole role : allRoles) {
        ParseQuery usersQuery = role.getRelation("users").getQuery();
        usersQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
        try {
            if(usersQuery.count() > 0) {
                userRoles.add(role);
                userRolesNames.add(role.getName().toString());
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }               

    GroupAdapter adapter = new GroupAdapter(this, userRolesNames);
    workspaces.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: You were almost there with your check against users, but you compare it to the user object, not just the ID. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably need to iterate through the roles, checking if the current user is in each of them. Sorry I can't provide you with some android code, as I am an iOS programmer, but this is an example of how you could do it with iOS, and hopefully you can port this to android. In iOS I would make a method, or maybe a category, for this code:

```
PFQuery *rolesQuery = [PFRole query]; 
NSArray *allRoles = [rolesQuery findObjects];
NSMutableArray *userRoles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
for (PFRole *role in allRoles) {
    PFQuery *usersQuery = [role relationforKey:@"users"].query;
    [usersQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
    if ([usersQuery countObjects]) {
        [userRoles addObject:role];
    }
}
```

Hope this puts you on the right path...

Comment: What exactly is the last if statement doing as I'm struggling to interpret that in Android?

Comment: PFQuery *usersQuery = [role relationforKey:@"users"].query;
    [usersQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
    These lines makes sure you only return roles containing the current user

    if ([usersQuery countObjects]) {
    This is the same as saying "If the query returns more than 0 results"

Comment: Argh, formatting! The simple answer to your question: This is the same as saying "If the query returns more than 0 results"

Comment: Finally managed to get it to work. Thanks so much for your help man. I'll post in the question what I ended up with but I feel you should still get the accepted answer as you gave me the logic. :)

Comment: Cheers, mate! Glad you got it to work. And thanks for posting the final code :-)

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this while trying to confirm something, and realised there's a much simpler way:

### Android

```
ParseQuery<ParseRole> query = ParseRole.getQuery();
query.whereEqualTo('users', ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseRole>() {
    public void done(List<ParseRole> roles, ParseException e) {
        // do your thing with the roles list
    }
});
```

And for the sake of others, here's the answer in a couple of other languages.

### iOS Objective-C

```
PFQuery *query = [PFRole query];
[query whereKey:@"users" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *roles, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    // Do something with the found roles
  }
}];
```

### iOS Swift

```
var query = PFRole.query();
query.whereKey('users', equalTo:PFUser.currentUser());
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (roles: [PFObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
    // do your thing with the roles
  }
}
```

### JavaScript

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
query.equalTo('users', Parse.User.current());
query.find().then(function(roles) {
  // do your thing with the roles array
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
ParseRole myroles= (ParseRole) new ParseQuery("Role").whereEqualTo("name", "AppName-"+currentuserid).getFirst();


Here  "name" -----------Column in Role Table

      "AppName" --------eg: "MyApp-23"   in your _User table



I think this helps...
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this would exactly work but this would only give me the Users from one specified Role? I just want all of the Roles of the Current User. How can this be achieved?